# React-native получить значение класса

Tags: javascript

Привет Всем. Помогите:) Всю голову уже поломал %)
есть такой класс

```
export default class MySensor extends React.Component {
  state = {
    Count: 0,
    startfrom: '',
    endfor: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this._subscribe();
  }

  _subscribe = () => {
     this.setState({
        Count: '100'
      });
  }

return MySensor.state.Count;

}
```

И есть класс использующий его.

```
import MySensor from 'react-native-progress/Bar';

export default class SensorIncrement extends React.Component {

      render() {
        let sensor = MySensor;
        return (
          <Text>{sensor + 1}</Text>
         );
      }
}
```

Не могу понять, как получить значение в переменную из класса.

Answer (score 0):

Ты присваиваешь класс в переменную sensor, если тебе нужны значения то создай экземпляр класса `MySensor`

`let sensor = new MySensor();`

Comment: Да, но получается, что так как первый класс не отрендерен, componentDidMount() не вызывается, и соответственно переменная не присваивается. Но он и не должен быть включен в рендер. Класс MySensor выполняет техническую часть. И как получить значение - ума не приложу :(